# From Hamiltonian to the Pulse Sequence

Tags: qiskit, quantum-algorithms, hamiltonian-simulation, matrix-representation

I know my Hamiltonian:

[image]

I know which unitary I want to have. Suppose that I want to have this matrix from Hamiltonian:

[image]

1. How can I find the pulse sequence to have this matrix from the Hamiltonian?
2. What is the analytical way to do that?
3. Is there any tool,any library, any algorithm to find the pulse sequence from the Hamiltonian? (or at least to find the unitary from the Hamiltonian)

I am looking for tools over github but for now I have not seen yet.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a whole branch of physics/engineering called "optimal control theory" which gives you numerical routines for finding the best control sequences to achieve a particular unitary. Perhaps try [this tutorial](https://arxiv.org/abs/0707.1883)?

If you're going to be doing this regularly, you may want to use an existing package. The one that I know of is called [GRAPE](https://www.physik.uni-siegen.de/quantenoptik/events/marialaach07/glaser_marialaach07.pdf) (the linked talk contains multiple useful links). It seems that qiskit provides [several options](https://qutip.org/docs/4.0.2/guide/guide-control.html).